# Building the string on $\{0,1\}$ alphabet with $\Omega(n^{2})$ different substrings

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorics-on-words

As we know the number of different substrings has the upper bound $O(n^{2})$.

Consider the strings on $\{0,1\}$ alphabet. Can I build a string with $\Omega(n^{2})$ different substrings?

Actually I was thinking about the Thue-Morse sequence.  We could use the fact that there are no two $s_1,s_2\in$ the Thue-Morse sequence, such that $s_1\cap s_2>0$.

Comment: Doing it for an explicit string may be hard (maybe not); but a randomly chosen string will have that property.

Comment: And this is *not* string theory.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I think that it's possible to build it by induction

Comment: Ok... It's not very hard at all. Thue-Morse will do the job; or just about anything else. Take the binary odometer (differences of Thue-Morse mod 2). Every 2nd term is a 1; then every 4th term is a 0; every 8th term is a 1 etc.. This is a Toeplitz sequence. Consider substrings of length $m$, where $m$ is in the range $n/4$ to $n/2$. From 4 consecutive symbols, you can deduce your position mod 2; from 8 consec symbols, you can deduce your position mod 4 etc. Hence there are at least something like $n/16$ $m$-substrings for each $m$ in this range. This gives $\Omega(n^2)$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas hm looks great . Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the $2n$-bit string $0^n1^n$. There is an injective map $\{1,\dotsc,n\}^2 \ni (i,j) \mapsto 0^i1^j \in \text{Sub}(0^n1^n)$, which shows that there are at least $n^2$ different substrings.